# How can I sync my Android SQLite database with a database on a server using json?

Tags: android, sqlite, synchronization

I have an Android app with a sqlite db. I want to sync the content of the database with one on a php server, using json. I have the login and address of the server, so I need just the way to start. 
How do I connect? Do I need to decide protocol, like http or https?

What is the first step?

I use this:

```
TelephonyManager tManager = (TelephonyManager)this.mCtx.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    String uid = tManager.getDeviceId();
```

To get a unique identifier to be sent with the request.

If I have a url, is this a way to go:

```
DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpost = new HttpPost(path);?
```

Any inputs or good tutorials that take if from the beginning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example using the Android [SyncAdapter](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/SampleSyncAdapter/index.html) framework, designed for syncing remote sources to the device.